# jQuery Validation plugin - Custom method comparing two select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have these two select type of HTML:

```
<label for="h_slat_type">Slat Type</label>
<select name="h_slat_type" id="h_slat_type">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected>Select</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">---------</option>
                    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
            </select>

<label for="v_slat_type">Slat Type</label>
<select name="v_slat_type" id="v_slat_type">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected>Select</option>
                    <option disabled="disabled">---------</option>
                    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
            </select>
```

The condition for validation to fail is when I have both `h_slat_type` and `v_slat_type` set as `2`.

In other words if:

`h_slat_type 1` = `v_slat_type 1` -> true

`h_slat_type 2` = `v_slat_type 1` -> true

`h_slat_type 1` = `v_slat_type 2` -> true

`h_slat_type 2` = `v_slat_type 2` -> false

The JS method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("typecheck", function(value, element) {
    return ($('#h_slat_type').val() == $('#v_slat_type').val());
}, "Horizontal Type 2 and Vertical Type 2 incompatible!");
```

What would work in this case? ty vm.

Comment: I also tried `return ($('#h_slat_type').val() + $('#v_slat_type').val()) == 4;` but I don't get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if($('#h_slat_type').val() == $('#v_slat_type').val())
       return true;
    else if ($('#h_slat_type').val()==1 && $('#v_slat_type').val()==2)
       return true;
    else if ($('#h_slat_type').val()==2 && $('#v_slat_type').val()==1)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
```

Comment: ty vm, I had to change the first line before I could get the expected result : `if($('#h_slat_type').val()==1 && $('#h_slat_type').val()==1)`

Comment: The first If for both of your first and last condition ( 1==1, 2==2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
{
var selection_1 = $('#h_slat_type').val();
var selection_2 = $('#v_slat_type').val();
if(selection_1=='2' && selection_2=='2') return false;
return true;
}
```